# Fluid simulation not showing smoke and flames

Tags: fluid-simulation

I have tried to follow the tutorial at [explosion réaliste](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=explosion%20blender&iax=videos&iai=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DInToncJLhVk&ia=videos) but I'm stuck when it comes to bake the fluid simulation. After calculation, I still get my particles as small balls, as before the simulation.

My file is there : [image]

Any idea?

P.S : in my cache directory, all subdirectories are empty except the "config" one.

Comment: In the tutorial, no material is set for the domain but the simulation shows flames and smoke.

Comment: Yes, but before that time, fire and smoke appear on it's display. If I use the same material he uses (principled volume tied to the volume entry of the material output node), I still have balls in solid mode and nothing in render mode. File updated.

Comment: Of course I baked it. A difference between version 2.9 and 3.2.2?

Comment: Baked it many times, with a resolution ranging from 32 to 128.

Comment: In the particle system for your "Bombe" object, you have render as Halo, which are small balls.   You should try to render as an object, with some suitable material.

Comment: Look at your Prin Volume .... documentation says "Blackbody emission for fire. Set to 1 for physically accurate intensity."

Comment: I just noticed your comment about only your "config" directory having files.   If you "free" your domain bake, does the config folder get removed (it should).   If not try deleting these outside blender (File manager) and try to bake again.   I downloaded your file again and have no such issue.  I also assume you have free space on your hard drive.

Comment: If I free my bake, the entire cache directory gets empty. And yes, I have enough space on my hard drive (774Go).

Comment: Now even I am frustrated with your problem.  It affects you and cannot be reproduced!  I will delete my Answer in the hopes it attracts more attention (unanswered questions often get more notice)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know the origin of the problem but I have found a way to eliminate it. Instead of using a cache directory in the same branch as my project, I tried to use a new one located in "C:\Blender\temp" and it works!

The problem can be reproduced : if I set the cache directory to what it was, no fire and smoke again.